# Nexus Proxy Repository to http://dynamicjasper.com FAILED

Tags: java, maven, nexus, dynamic-reports

I'm trying to create a Nexus Proxy Repository to http://nexus.fdvs.com.ar/content/groups/public/, but we have only problems!!!! When I try buid my maven project, my Nexus does not find the DynamicJasper:4.0.2 artfact and the bellow error happens:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project siepa-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.indra.cartoes:siepa-web:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:jar:4.0.2 in nexus (http://nexus.sispcs.web/nexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]

Any idea about these problem?

Thanks for your attention and time.

I have founded the problem.
Add proxy repository to Nexus Public Repository and error finish.
But now another error have emerged:

Failed to transfer file: http://nexus.sispcs.web/nexus/content/groups/public/ar/com/fdvs/DynamicJasper/4.0.2/DynamicJasper-4.0.2.pom. Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Gateway

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved.
Really it was necessary add the target proxy repository to Nexus Public Repository.

Thx for all.

Answer (score 0):

The first URL you reference returns an error.

Check that the artifact is actually available manually.

Comment: Yes, artifact exists in remote repository, the Nexus Server has firewall rules to find it. We have did a wget to download the artfact and it works fine.

Comment: Then I need more details about your setup and what fails specifically. E.g. try the build off a empty local Maven repository.